# What is the type of an auto const & map iterator? c++

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator

I need to fix some bugs on an older project of mine, and I thought that this is the perfect occasion to refactor some of the code.

I have a map of the following structure:

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, myClass*> > ComponentMap;
```

Somewhere in I need to iterate through some of the underlying sub-maps and I used the following:

```
for (std::map<std::string, myClass* >::iterator iter = ComponentMap[compNameString].begin(); iter != ComponentMap[compNameString].end(); ++iter)
{
 //some code
 if (IsComponentOfType(iter, sCOMP_PRINCIPAL))
     iter->second->GetComponentValue(date, compName, 00);
 //some more code
}
```

The IsComponentOfType function has the following declaration:

```
bool IsComponentOfType(const std::map<std::string, myClass* >::iterator & MapIter, const sCOMPONENT_TYPE & Type)
```

My question is:
When I rewrote the for loop as such:

```
for (auto const& iter: ComponentMap[compNameString])
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
IsComponentOfType(const std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>> &,const sCOMPONENT_TYPE &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'const std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>> &'
```

Of what type do I need to rewrite the first argument of the function in order to "make" the c++11 syntax work?

Comment: `auto const& iter` with that syntax it wont be an iterator, it'll be what the iterator points to, which iirc is a pair of const string, myClass*. (edit: in fact your error message tells you that: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'`)

Comment: The error tells you the type: `const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>`. `_Kty` and `_Ty` are the key and value template arguments of the map.

Comment: Taking an iterator as argument for your function is poor design. It should take a value, reference, or constant reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, myClass*> > ComponentMap;
```

and

```
for (auto const& iter: ComponentMap[compNameString]) {}
```

The type of `iter` would be deduced to be, effectively, `std::map<std::string, myClass*>::value_type const&`, which is equal to `std::pair<std::string const, myClass*> const&`.

What you get with a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is ***not*** an iterator, it's a *value*, or a reference to a value. Each value correspond to an element in the container you loop over.

Comment: In this case, it's not a value, but a `const` reference to a value.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 for loops loop over elements.

Back up and return to the working loop code.  Then add the line `auto const& elem=*iter;` at the top of the loop.

Next, line by line, eliminate use of `iter` in body of loop.  Ensure the code compiles and runs after you change each line.

```
if (IsComponentOfType(iter,
```

change this to

```
if (IsComponentOfType(elem,
```

in C++03 code and make it compile (modify `IsComponentOfType` to take `std::pair<std::string const, myClass*>  const&`).

```
iter->second
```

change this to

```
elem.second
```

once this is done (and similar elsewhere), change loop to C++11 style:

```
for (auto const& elem: ComponentMap[compNameString])
```

and done.

Comment: From OP: "My question is: When I rewrote the for loop as such: `for (auto const& iter: ComponentMap[compNameString])`" They already did what you suggested, that's why they got the error in the first place.

Comment: @Borgleader Yakk is suggesting to undo that step, do the other steps first (including changing the declaration of `IsComponentOfType`), and only after that is done change to the C++ `for` loop, at which point everything should just work. This answer is a refactoring recipe that gets you from point A (old code, working) to point B (C++11 style, working) via small intermediate steps, all of which produce working code.

Comment: @melpomene Huh, that was absolutely not clear to me.

Comment: @borg clarified.

Answer (score 1):

[Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

> `attr(optional) for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement`
>
> range_declaration - a declaration of a named variable, **whose type is the type of the element of the sequence represented by range_expression, or a reference to that type**. Often uses the auto specifier for automatic type deduction.

Since `iter` is a value,
Instead of:

```
iter->second->GetComponentValue(date, compName, 00);
```

This should work:

```
iter.second->GetComponentValue(date, compName, 00);
```